# javascript new Date() issue

Tags: javascript, date

I'm facing a date issue with `new Date()` function. May i know why is this weired output is coming.

```
new Date(1984, 12, 13)
Sun Jan 13 1985 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Here the month should be December but it results me with Jan.

Comment: JS Months start at 0

Comment: `12` *is* January, not December.

Answer (score 0):

January is 0 in javascript , so javascript is counting up and is adding the date. That's why you get this result.

Comment: Not even worth an answer in my opinion

Comment: Actually you are right @mplungjan